# jQuery Switch Buttons, Can you add if clicked and if clicks == 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, button, onclicklistener

I have a switch button like this:

[image: this one]

I want to make it so that it is a dark mode button. When clicking once, it uses jQuery to invert the colors of specified class and 2, when you click again, it returns to the default.
Here's how I plan to do it. I have a variable, clicks, that increase on the first click by one. When the button is clicked again, I want JS to detect that it was clicked and clicks == 1;

I have a few questions,

Is there a way to do that, `if( detect clicked phase && clicks == 1;){}`
Assuming there is a way to do so, is there a way for jQuery to undo the actions of a previous button? For example, you click once, it makes everything dark. Click again and it makes everything back to normal?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Wouldn't you just toggle a class?

Comment: Have you just toggle a class?